# Is there a way to add properties or component data to looped objects with Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, alpine.js

Essentially I'm receiving JSON from the server and would like to add properties to the objects I'm looping or the `x-data` of the component, is this possible with alpine.js?

The data is something that will be requested on an interval and looks something like:

```
let teams = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Person 1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Person 2'},
    ...
];
```

What I'd like to do is add a new property `favourite` to the looped `team` object, with default set to `false` or add it as component data. I plan to use this property to filter the list later on. At the moment I have:

```
<template x-for="team in teams" :key="team.id">
    <tr>
        <td x-text="team.name"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" x-model="favourite">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

I have tried a few things to get this working, such as using:

`x-data="{ team: team, favourite: false }"`

On both the `tr` and `template` tag as well as without passing the `team` object to the `x-data` directive. It seems like there is a clash between the `x-for` and `x-data` directives as this throws an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: team is not defined`

I have also tried using `x-init` alongside the `x-data` directive to no avail.

At this stage I'm wondering if I'll have to switch to another JS library to get this working (recommendations welcome if necessary) or if my approach is fundamentally wrong.

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle what you should be doing is adding the "favourite" field before it gets to the `x-for`.

For example if you're loading `teams` using `fetch` you could do:

```html
<div
  x-data="{ teams: [] }"
  x-init="setInterval(() => {
    fetch('/teams-url').then(res => res.json()).then(teamsData => {
      teams = teamsData.map(team => ({ favourite: false, ...team }));
    });
  }, 1000);"
>
```

I also noticed that your example is using `v-model` and `v-text`, which should be `x-model` and `x-text` respectively.

Comment: I had thought this might be the case, the problem is that the favourite is user specific data and something I will be tracking with local storage, so it's something I don't want to reset when I pull in the data again. You're right, in the example it should be ```x-``` not ```v-```, the downside of late night programming

Comment: With that example, you can load the favourites from local storage and hydrate (instead of setting favourite to false, you can decide based on what's in local storage)